# Boolean formula for graph 3color

Tags: graph, boolean-expression

For a given undirected graph `G=(V,E)` I'm trying to construct a Boolean polynomially computable formula `ϕ` with the following property: `ϕ` is satisfiable iff vertices of `G` can be colored in 3 colors with the following condition: For any edge `(u, v) ∈ E`, if `u` and `v` have different colors, then there exists `w ∈ V` such that `(u, w) ∈ E, (v, w) ∈ E`, and `w` has the third color (different from both `u` and `v`). Here it is ok
that two vertices of the same color may be connected by an edge.

So I need that all nodes must get a color (3 expression) + no nodes can get more than one color (9 expressions) + ... here I'm in trouble. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aren't all graphs trivially colorable by those conditions, e.g. make every node blue? Then any statement quantified as 'for any edge `(u,v)` where `u` and `v` have different colors' is trivially true?

Comment: @kcsquared Thanks. But if we color all vertices with the same color, the condition "For any edge (u,v)∈E, if u and v have different colors, there exists..." never happens, right?

Comment: That is correct. If you want different colors, you would need to introduce that through a separate constraint. Right now, it's quite easy to find an equivalent formula: it's always True